# What is CompositeDefinitionSource in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Recently after upgrading Gradle Android Studio automatically added this to my `.idea/gradle.xml` :

```
    <compositeConfiguration>
      <compositeBuild compositeDefinitionSource="SCRIPT" />
    </compositeConfiguration>
```

What is the purpose of this change?

Comment: [Narendra\_Nath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13533028) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66771446) saying "This a doc from the gradle docs which talks about CompositeDefinitionSource in detail. [https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)"

Answer (score 0):

First there is several points to understand:

- The file `.idea/gradle.xml` is used by Android Studio to store the Gradle project settings.
- According to the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_build_intro):

> A composite build is simply a build that includes other builds.

- According to the [documentation of IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#gradle_composite_build) on which Android Studio is based, there is two ways to define a Gradle composite build either through the IDE or through the `settings.gradle` file.
- According to the [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/gradle/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/settings/CompositeDefinitionSource.java) of IntelliJ IDEA the value of `compositeDefinitionSource` can be either `SCRIPT` or `IDE`.

To answer your question, the purpose of the `compositeConfiguration` element in the `.idea/gradle.xml` file is to define as a default the  Gradle composite build by script. If you set a Gradle composite build through the IDE this value will change.